# ktor running fat jar throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException::Packages and file facades are not yet supported in Kotlin reflection

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Below is the basic ktor file which is running properly from IDE but I created a fat jar file with "mvn install" and running it throws below exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Packages and file facades are not yet supported in Kotlin reflection. Meanwhile please use Java reflection to inspect this class: class com.tech.ApplicationKt

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    embeddedServer(Netty, 8080){
        routing{
            get("/demo"){
                call.respondText("Hello demo")
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

I tried executing jar on Java 11 and 8 but I am getting same exception.

Comment: What version of ktor are you using? Maybe even show us your build.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this out by following the official guide on ktor.io for setup with maven.

Afterwards I followed https://ktor.io/servers/deploy/packing/fatjar.html#fat-jar-maven for the jar compilation.

I encountered 2 issues:

1. I first tried the `install:install` task from the IntelliJ Maven side bar, but actually you have to use the lifecycle methods `install` or just `package`.
2. I had to adjust the `mainClass` attribute of the maven assembly plugin to match that of my own, e.g `path.to.your.package.ServerKt` or whatever your file is called.

Once I fixed those two everything worked fine.

If you still have issues, please show us you build file.

Comment: It is working fine after adjusting mainClass in maven assembly plugin. Thanks for pointing that.